# mysql partition enabled or not?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

When I run `show variables like 'have_partitioning';` it return empty record. When I run `show plugins` I got this result  ***partition | ACTIVE | STORAGE ENGINE|NULL    | GPL|*** My MySQL version is 5.6.29 and I'm running it in CentOS. What I have to do to get ***Yes*** when I run `'show variables like 'have_partitinoing`

Comment: "What I have to do to get" -- Sorry; the earth has moved out from under you.  _Why_ do you have to run that old query?  Why do you need to ask anything other than Version >= 5.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**have_partitioning** variable is removed from **MySQL version is 5.6.29**. That's why it is not showing.Instead of it you can use **show plugins** for knowing partition is enabled or not.If status value is Active then it is enabled.You can also disable partition by adding skip-partition=True while starting mysql server.